# Is there an SDL2 function for getting the current state of the mouse wheel?

Tags: sdl-2

For example, SDL_GetMouseState() can be used to get the current state of the mouse. Is there an analogous function that gets the current state of the mouse wheel?

I know I can handle the SDL_MouseWheelEvent that is generated instead to get the mouse wheel state, but I would rather poll the mouse wheel state directly if possible.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to poll the scroll state when it will be neutral _unless_ a mouse wheel event is triggered?

Comment: That's the way I have handled input for every other type of device my game engine recognizes (e.g. keyboard input, game controller digital input, mouse button input, and game controller analog stick input). Rather than using an event queue, the engine just polls the state of these devices directly every tick. I figured it would make sense to also poll the mouse scroll wheel state in a similar way. Is there any advantage to using the event queue over polling the state directly?

Comment: There isn't a direct advantage to using an event queue. In fact some things, like [polling the mouse](https://github.com/letoram/SDL2/blob/master/src/events/SDL_mouse.c#L110C1-L110C13), can be fast. However, you have to understand that polling everything each tick takes time. Depending on the amount of things you're polling it can be faster to just call `SDL_PollEvent` once and determine what changed. I can't read the mind of the SDL developers but I assume there is no function for polling the scroll wheel for the very same reason I used in my first comment.